Rebuild sometimes fails with error '\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net4.8'
I have a multi-targeted solution which fails to rebuild consistently and keeps reporting the error

Error NETSDK1005  Assets file ' ...\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't
have a target for 'net4.8'. Ensure that restore has run and
that you have included 'net4.8' in the TargetFrameworks for your
project.

Occasionally a second rebuild will work, but not always.
Building the projects individually always works but that is tedious.
An absolutely minimal project which contains two projects also exhibits the same problem.
Project1
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Project2
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net4.8</TargetFrameworks>  
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

(And yes, apart from the solution, that's it - no code and no nuget packages involved in the test solution)
Using VS 2022 Version 17.9.6
Has anyone any ideas?

I've seen this error before, but for me it only happens if I do a full rebuild, on a "normal" build or just "run" I've not seen the issue. If it happens, I rebuild the project throwing the error and then it's fine again.

Would you try manually use dotnet restore and then try to rebuild your solution?

Manually using dotnet restore either on the solution or individual projects does not make any difference.

As you mentioned your solutions sometimes build successfully but sometimes not,can you share a detailed steps about how to reproduce it?
You can also try delete the obj/ folder under your solutions file and restore&rebuild it once again.

Deleting the obj (or bin) folders does not make any difference. My real project is inconsistent and I have not been able to say why. The example test solution consistently fails.

As I am unable to reproduce the issue I assume there are some missing dependencies.Also not everything on .NET Framework 4.8 is available on .NET Standard 2.0 but I have no clue about your project detail.
